# android httpclient send post using the url as parameters?

Tags: android, httpclient

I am sending data from android to the web, which is using httpclient using the code like this

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://host");
    List<BasicNameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", "signIn"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",u));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass));
    UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps,HTTP.UTF_8);
    httppost.setEntity(p_entity);
```

I am a little confused, if this code is putting the parameters into the url as argument, like `url?method=a&email=b&password=c`
or putting the parameters into the post body

What I should do is to construct a http post to this url url?method=a with email and password parameters in post body

Comment: May be this can help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315415/how-send-data-to-website-by-using-android-app/16315825#16315825

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about [HttpMethods](https://www.google.com.cu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CFEQFjAD&url=http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp&ei=WGOxUe3IFsP3O76rgZAG&usg=AFQjCNFbrRI8ZNXZ7cyqdNgMrb0gQFcrQg&bvm=bv.47534661,d.ZWU).By definition, HttpPost pass the parameters on its body, and not in the query string. HttpGet in the other hand, should pass the parameters in the query string. 
Besides, the ***entity*** here stands for the body.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit confusing that you mix URL parameters and post data in the same request. It's not unheard of but I would recommend that you do your login using another URL, for instance http://www.yourhost.com/signin and POST username and password.

You should also look into using a wrapper around your HTTP calls. Working with the DefaultHttpClient will have you writing a lot more code than if you used [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp), Volley or the excellent [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). Example using Android Async Http Client (with mixed URL and POST params):

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("email", "u");
params.put("password", "pass");
client.post("http://host?method=signIn", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        // handle response here
    }
});
```