# fields are not inserting into mysql Database android

Tags: php, android, mysql

[image]I am trying to store an android form data into MySQL database but the thing is other fields are completely fine and their values are storing into DB, the only name, and email are not inserting into DB. All code is fine, I am not even getting any errors. Please tell me what I have done wrong. If you can see the picture, there are some fields which are taking the value as 0. I don't understand why.Please tell me a proper solution if you know

This is my Code
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etid, etname, etstorename, etemail, etphone, etdoj;
    Button btnregister;
    TextView tvlogin;
    private ParseContent parseContent;
    PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;
    private final int RegTask = 5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(this);
        parseContent = new ParseContent(this);

        if(preferenceHelper.getIsLogin()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,WelcomeActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        }
        etid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etmi_id);
        etname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etname);
        etstorename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etstore_name);
        etemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etemail);
        etphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etphone);
        etdoj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdoj);
        btnregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        tvlogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvlogin);

        tvlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    register();
                } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void register() throws IOException, JSONException {

        if (!AndyUtils.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Internet is required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        AndyUtils.showSimpleProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(AndyConstants.Params.MI_ID, etid.getText().toString());
        map.put(AndyConstants.Params.NAME, etname.getText().toString());
        map.put(AndyConstants.Params.STORE_NAME, etstorename.getText().toString());
        map.put(AndyConstants.Params.EMAIL, etemail.getText().toString());
        map.put(AndyConstants.Params.PHONE, etphone.getText().toString());
        map.put(AndyConstants.Params.DOJ, etdoj.getText().toString());
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
            protected String doInBackground(Void[] params) {
                String response="";
                try {
                    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(AndyConstants.ServiceType.REGISTER);
                    response = req.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST).withData(map).sendAndReadString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    response=e.getMessage();
                }
                return response;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //do something with response
                Log.d("newwwss", result);
                onTaskCompleted(result, RegTask);
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    private void onTaskCompleted(String response,int task) {
        Log.d("responsejson", response.toString());
        AndyUtils.removeSimpleProgressDialog();  //will remove progress dialog
        switch (task) {
            case RegTask:

                if (parseContent.isSuccess(response)) {

                    parseContent.saveInfo(response);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registered Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,WelcomeActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    this.finish();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, parseContent.getErrorMessage(response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**PreferenceHelper.java**

```
public class PreferenceHelper {
    private final String MI_ID = "mi_id";
    private final String NAME = "name";
    private final String STORE_NAME = "store_name";
    private final String EMAIL = "email";
    private final String PHONE = "phone";
    private final String DOJ = "doj";
    private SharedPreferences app_prefs;
    private Context context;

    public PreferenceHelper(Context context) {
        app_prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("shared",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void putIsLogin(boolean loginorout) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = app_prefs.edit();
        edit.putBoolean(PHONE, loginorout);
        edit.apply();
    }
    public boolean getIsLogin() {
        return app_prefs.getBoolean(PHONE, false);
    }

    public void putMi_id(String loginorout) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = app_prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(MI_ID, loginorout);
        edit.apply();
    }
    public String getMi_id() {
        return app_prefs.getString(MI_ID, "");
    }

    public void putName(String loginorout) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = app_prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(NAME, loginorout);
        edit.apply();
    }
    public String getName() {
        return app_prefs.getString(NAME, "");
    }

    public void putStore_name(String loginorout) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = app_prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(STORE_NAME, loginorout);
        edit.apply();
    }
    public String getStore_name() {
        return app_prefs.getString(STORE_NAME, "");
    }

    public void putEmail(String loginorout) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = app_prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(EMAIL, loginorout);
        edit.apply();
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return app_prefs.getString(EMAIL, "");
    }
    public void putPhone(String loginorout) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = app_prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(PHONE, loginorout);
        edit.apply();
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return app_prefs.getString(PHONE, "");
    }

    public void putDoj(String loginorout) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = app_prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(DOJ, loginorout);
        edit.commit();
    }
    public String getDoj() {
        return app_prefs.getString(DOJ, "");
    }
 }
```

**Simplereg.php**

```
<?php

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  // echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];  // /home1/demonuts/public_html
 //including the database connection file
       include_once("dbConfig.php");
        $mi_id = $_POST['mi_id'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $store_name = $_POST['store_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $doj = $_POST['doj'];


     if($mi_id == '' || $name == '' || $store_name == '' || $email == '' || $phone == '' ||$doj == ''){
            echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "Parameter missing!") );
     }else{

            $query= "SELECT * FROM registerdemo WHERE name='$name'";
            $result= mysqli_query($con, $query);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1){
               echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "Username already exist!") );
            }else{ 
            $name = $_POST['name'];

             $query1 = "INSERT INTO registerdemo (mi_id,name,store_name,email,phone,doj) VALUES ('$mi_id','$name','$store_name','$email','$phone','$doj')";
             if(mysqli_query($con,$query1)){

                 $query2= "SELECT * FROM registerdemo WHERE name='$name'";
                         $result2= mysqli_query($con, $query2);
                     $emparray = array();
                         if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0){  
                         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)!=NULL) {
                                     $emparray[] = $row;
                                   }
                         } 
                echo json_encode(array( "status" => "true","message" => "Successfully registered!" , "data" => $emparray) );
             }else{
                 echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "Error occured, please try again!") );
            }
        }
     }
     } else{
            echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "Error occured, please try again!") );
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: Is that Java and not PHP?

Comment: Yeah, what does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: The Android code is Java, the server side code PHP with MySQL.

Comment: Use prepared statements and then check the error output.

Comment: I have uploaded all the code.

Comment: I tried. But first there is no error and second, i echoed $name and then as well its blank.

Comment: *"is no error"* - I don't see any error checking via php and the queries. Do that, then update your post to contain what they are (if any). I can't help with java.

Comment: Is the non-insertion of name and email happening all the time or just on certain names/email addresses?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315415/how-send-data-to-website-by-using-android-app refer this

Comment: post values of `AndyConstants.Params.EMAIL`

Comment: public class Params {
        public static final String MI_ID = "mi_id";
        public static final String NAME = "name";
        public static final String STORE_NAME = "store_name";
        public static final String EMAIL = "email";
        public static final String PHONE = "phone";
        public static final String DOJ = "doj";
       }

Comment: The name and email data fields look like there numeric. Change to appropriate text field.

Comment: Its varchar only

Comment: var  char? what length?